# Serializar relacionamentos Doctrine

Tags: php, json, doctrine

Como faço um json com os relacionamentos de uma entity no doctrine? já procurei por ai e fiz algumas tentativas mas nada que funcionasse até agora.

Estou fazendo assim e retorna o json normal(sem os relacionamentos):

```
$list = $this->getEm()->createquery('select u from Ticket\Entity\Ticket u');
$query = $list->getResult(\Doctrine\ORM\Query::HYDRATE_ARRAY);
           return new \Zend\View\Model\JsonModel($query);
```

Relacionamento da classe Ticket com usuario:

```
/**
 * @ORM\ManyToOne(targetEntity="Ticket\Entity\Usuario", inversedBy="ticket")
 * @ORM\JoinColumn(name="usuario_id", referencedColumnName="id")
 * 
 */ 
protected $usuario;
```

output:

`[{"id":41,"description":"teste"},{"id":38,"description":"teste1"}]`

Tem algum "truque" p fazer isso? vlw

Comment: O que você quer fazer? Trazer as informações do usuário junto com o ticket?

Answer (score 0):

Você precisa apenas trazer o usuário junto com o ticket na hora de executar a *query*. Quanto ao restante do código, nada muda.

```
$list = $this
    ->getEm()
    ->createQuery('
        SELECT t, u
        FROM Ticket\Entity\Ticket t
        JOIN t.usuario u');
```